# Linux kernel - alloc_skb vs dev_alloc_skb vs netdev_alloc_skb

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Which is the difference between `alloc_skb`, `dev_alloc_skb` and `netdev_alloc_skb`?

I've read a lot of mailing lists, articles and posts about this question, but none of them gave me a thorough answer. They're all very old or not exhaustive.

Comment: There is also a difference that netdev_alloc_skb() reserves additional 32 bytes (by skb_reserve()) in front of buffer. But I also beg for someone more experienced in kernel to tell us the exact difference between those functions, and what was the intention behind creation of them.

Answer (score 0):

alloc_skb() is the basic function,

netdev_alloc_skb() call alloc_skb() to get skb, then assign it's input parameter **dev** to skb->dev

dev_alloc_skb() is same with  netdev_alloc_skb(), but dev is **NULL**,

```
*static inline struct sk_buff *dev_alloc_skb(unsigned int length)
{
         return netdev_alloc_skb(NULL, length);
}*
```

Comment: So what's the difference between `alloc_skb` and `dev_alloc_skb` since both of them have `skb->dev = NULL`?

Comment: 1. both have skb->dev = NULL

2.  netdev_alloc_skb () call  __alloc_skb  by following parameter      GFP_ATOMIC ,   SKB_ALLOC_RX,   NUMA_NO_NODE